# Create onClick event before its in dom

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onclick

I have a function that pushes html into an array, when it is done it returns the html and the html is pushed to the dom by a other function using jQuery's .html.

The function that pushes the html has a parameter that contains a method that should be called when the table is clicked.

But when I try to use onclick it renders my function as a string (The entire contents of the function).

What am I doing wrong?

```
function GenerateTapHeader(TabName, clickCallbackFunction) {
    var tmpTapHeaderHTML = new Array();

    tmpTapHeaderHTML.push('<table id="Table_' + TabName + '" class="TapHeader" onclick="' + clickCallbackFunction + '">');
    tmpTapHeaderHTML.push('<tr>');
    tmpTapHeaderHTML.push('<td></td><td></td>');
    tmpTapHeaderHTML.push('<td><span></span></td>');
    tmpTapHeaderHTML.push('<td></td>');
    tmpTapHeaderHTML.push('<td><div>' + TabName + '</div></td>');
    tmpTapHeaderHTML.push('<td></td>');
    tmpTapHeaderHTML.push('<td></td>');
    tmpTapHeaderHTML.push('</tr>');
    tmpTapHeaderHTML.push('</table>');

    return tmpTapHeaderHTML.join('');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hm you cant do this because there has to be a reference in the global scope to run the onclick function say you got

```
<a oncklick="runme()">runme()</a>
```

you would have to have the function runme present in the global scope (window)
so you would have to do this (clickCallbackFunctionName must be a string containing the NAME of the function you want to call):

```
function GenerateTapHeader(TabName, clickCallbackFunctionName) {
    var tmpTapHeaderHTML = new Array();

    tmpTapHeaderHTML.push('<table id="Table_' + TabName + '" class="TapHeader" onclick="' + clickCallbackFunctionName + '();">');
    tmpTapHeaderHTML.push('<tr>');
    tmpTapHeaderHTML.push('<td></td><td></td>');
    tmpTapHeaderHTML.push('<td><span></span></td>');
    tmpTapHeaderHTML.push('<td></td>');
    tmpTapHeaderHTML.push('<td><div>' + TabName + '</div></td>');
    tmpTapHeaderHTML.push('<td></td>');
    tmpTapHeaderHTML.push('<td></td>');
    tmpTapHeaderHTML.push('</tr>');
    tmpTapHeaderHTML.push('</table>');

    return tmpTapHeaderHTML.join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wait until after you've added the table to the dom and then do the following:

```
$('#Table_' + TabName).click(function(){
    clickCallbackFunction();
});
```